# Search for lines not commented out

Tags: c++, regex, perl

I have a habit of commenting out printf() calls that others have left in the code so I don't pollute the log with thousands of lines, which makes it hard to see if any new error messages have been logged.

Anyhow, the codebase has lots of printf() statements, but I would like to find only the ones that are not commented out. They are always commented out using the C++ single line comment syntax of two forward slashes (//).

The slashes may be at the beginning of the line, immediately before, or anywhere in between.

Examples:

```
//             printf(…);
             //printf(…);
      //       printf(…);
```

I want to match only printf() statements that are still live:

```
              printf(…);
```

Comment: `perl -ne 'print if m|^\s*printf|' *c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match `printf` statements which are only preceded by whitespace, then perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
perl -lne 'print if /^\s*printf/' inFile
```

Comment: Your rephrasing the question made it obvious. I was too focused on the comment part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep printf <code files> | grep -v '^[[:space:]]*//'
```

Comment: I'm looking to match lines that contain NSLog and are not commented out. This regex matches all lines that begin with a comment.

Comment: @MarkThalman: no, the `-v` filters those lines out (invert match).

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It matches lines where the NSLog() is commented out.

Comment: @MarkThalman: doesn't for me. Post up an actual test case. Keep in mind this doesn't deal with `/* */`-style comments.

Comment: grep NSLog *.m | grep -v '//' worked for me. The grep on OS X is really lame and doesn't deal with posix extensions very well.

Comment: That's why a Perl solution is most of the times better, because there's a greater chance that it works everywhere (even on Windows).

Comment: @SlavenRezic: unless you don't have Perl. (grep is really common, and as it's bundled with Busybox, it's available on e.g. embedded Linux platforms. This isn't always true of Perl.)